# Explicit synchronisation of single model using angularFireCollection

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using version 0.3.0 of angularFire to wire up an AngularJS app to Firebase. I would like to use explicit synchronisation of a single model on an edit form.

I tried to use angularFireCollection rather than angularFire as per the [documentation](http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#explicit), using `$scope.questions = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(fbUrl + 'questions/' + $routeParams.id));` in my controller, but as the name implies, it only appears to work for collections and not single models.

I don't want to retrieve a potentially large collection and then search for a particular model, so I hacked around the problem by using angularFire and creating a copy, which I revert to if the user cancels the edit, but due to implicit synchronisation, this has the side effect of broadcasting the changes while editing the model.

I would like to know what is the recommended recipe for handling this use case. Should I resort to using the Firebase API directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in this case it makes sense to use the Firebase API directly. In general I think it helps to think of AngularFire as a complement to, not a replacement for, the Firebase API. It dramatically simplifies a few common use cases (e.g. live updates among collections via `angularFireCollection`), but you'd be hard pressed to simplify explicit updating of a single model via the Firebase API:

```
var questionRef = new Firebase(fbUrl + 'questions/' + $routeParams.id)
questionRef.update({fieldToUpdate: "newData"})
```

Which should be just what you need in your edit form.